# «Я помню в Вязьме старый дом» — синтаксический разбор

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

*Я помню **в Вязьме** старый дом.*
Каким членом предложения является "в Вязьме"? Мне кажется, что это определение.

Comment: Определение, вероятно. Примерно как в "жить в доме напротив". Да и легко переделывается в придаточное определительное: Я помню старый дом, который находился в Вязьме.

Comment: Спасибо! Я так и думала. Придаточное определительное - веский аргумент.